# How to install CentOS 6.6 linux on an OCZ RevoDrive3 X2 PCI SSD

Tags: centos, ssd

This took me a week, so here's the problem, and solution.

From CentOS 6.5 onwards, the driver mvsas.ko recognizes the OCZ SSD... wrongly.  It shows up as 4 small slow SSDs, instead of one big fast one.

How to fix this is below.  Also, in general, how to load custom drivers or deal with broken ones during linux booting is explained with these concepts

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Unix & Linux StackExchange site. Can you split your answer out from your question? It's OK to write your own answer to your question. I've temporarily put your question on hold, once you fix that we'd be more than happy to reopen it. It's not a bad question or anything, just not in the correct format, so I put it on hold merely to block others from flagging it and giving you a bad experience, let me know through comments if you're not sure what to do or need any help.

Comment: I'll reopen it, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks slm - fixed. sorry I got it wrong to start with - I think I've tried to do stuff on here in the past and been blocked for no reputation - I guess I wrongly assumed it was going to block me from answering my own question as well.  One reason I posted here, is because in my week-long quest to fix this problem, I got a hit from someone who half-solved it years ago and posted a howto themself... that person was me, and I'd forgotten!  This should save a lot of people a lot of time - google failed to help me in any easy way to figure all this out (before now)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the overview:

1. you need to boot an installer, then use Ctrl-Alt-F2 to drop to a
   shell when the install screen starts
2. you need to remove the mvsas
   module, and add the ocz10xx.ko one in it's place.  Be aware that
   there's several floading around - the big noew one does not work -
   you need the one "2760604 Dec 10  2012 ocz10xx.ko"
3. you need to
   load it (insmod + depmod)
4. you need to complete the install, but
   NOT reboot at the end
5. you need to drop back into the shell and
   add the driver into the initrd and kernel tree of your mounted
   install, and remove mvsas again, depmod -a -b `pwd` (from
   /mnt/sysimage), and reboot
6. you probably need to disable kdump -
   it rebuilds initrd which might break stuff.

Here's all the stuff I typed to make mine work. Pardon all the wasteful crud in there, but if you want me to save you a week of pain, this is better than nothing :-)
Note that I used DD to back up my SSD install to my hard drive - you don't need that step unless you're planning to break more stuff later, and want to be able to quickly "undo" it.

This is generally the procedure for doing anything with CentOS where you've got to mess with custom driver modules.

`5  fdisk -l
    6  lsscsi
    7  df
    8  dir /mnt/stage2/
    9  alias dir='ls -Flatr'
   10  dir /mnt/stage2/
   11  mkdir /1
   12  lsscsi
   13  mount /dev/sdk1 /1
   14  cd modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/
   15  cp -a /1/ocz10xx.ko .
   16  dir
   17  rmmod mvsas
   18  insmod ocz10xx.ko 
   19  cd /
   20  find | grep mvsas
   21  find | grep mvsas|grep -v ko
   22  cd find | grep mvsas|grep -v ko
   23  dir
   24  cp -a /1/ocz10xx.ko mvsas.ko
   25  rm mvsas.ko.gz 
   26  gzip mvsas.ko 
   27  dir
   28  lsscsi
   29  depmoda -a
   30  cd /
   31  depmod -a
   38  lsscsi
   39  dir
   40  find | grep ocz
   41  find | grep ocz | grep ko
   42  df
   43  cd /mnt/sysimage/
   44  find | grep mvsas
   45  cd /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64//kernel//drivers/scsi/mvsas/
   46  pwd
   47  dir
   48  cp -a mvsas.ko.gz /mnt/sysimage/
   49  cp -a /modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/ocz10xx.ko mvsas.ko
   50  rm mvsas.ko.gz 
   51  gzip mvsas.ko 
   52  cd ..
   53  cd ..
   54  cd ..
   55  cd ..
   56  cd ..
   57  cd ..
   58  find | grep extra
   59  pwd
   60  cd /mnt
   61  cd sysimage/
   62  find | grep extra
   63  find | grep extra$
   64  pwd
   65  cd lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/
   66  dir
   67  cp -a /modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/ocz10xx.ko mvsas.ko
   68  rm mvsas.ko 
   69  cp -a /modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/ocz10xx.ko .
   70  dir
   71  pwd
   72  cd ..
   73  cd ..
   74  pwd
   75  cd ..
   76  cd ..
   77  pwd
   78  depmod -a -b pwd
   79  cd boot/
   80  dir
   81  mkdir in
   82  cd in
   83  zcat ../initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img |cpio -ivdum
   84  find | grep ocz
   85  dir
   86  pwd
   87  find | grep ko
   88  cd lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/mvsas/
   89  dir
   90  mv mvsas.ko /mnt/sysimage/
   91  cp -a /modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/ocz10xx.ko .
   92  mv ocz10xx.ko  mvsas.ko
   93  dir
   94  pwd
   95  cd ..
   96  cd ..
   97  cd ..
   98  cd ..
   99  cd ..
  100  find | grep extra
  101  cd ..
  102  find | grep extra
  103  cd ..
  104  find | grep extra
  105  dir
  106  dir ..
  107  find * | cpio -o -H newc | gzip >../initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.imgA 
  108  df
  109  pwd
  110  depmod -a -b pwd
  111  find * | cpio -o -H newc | gzip >../initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.imgA 
  112  cd ..
  113  dir
  114  mv initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img.ori
  115  mv initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.imgA initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img
  116  dir
  117  dd if=/dev/zer of=zero bs=8225280
  118  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=8225280
  119  rm zero 
  120  fdisk -l
  121  lsscsi
  122  fdisk -l
  123  pwd
  124  df
  125  cd ..
  126  dir
  127  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=8225280
  128  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero2 bs=8225280
  129  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero3 bs=8225280
  130  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero4 bs=8225280 &
  131  dir /y
  132  dir y
  133  mkdir y/virgin
  134  cp -a boot y/virgin/
  135  fg
  136  dir
  137  fg
  138  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero5 bs=8225280 &
  139  ls -lsa
  140  cp -a b* c* d* e* h* l* m* n* o* p* r* s* t* u* v* y/virgin &
  141  ls -lsa
  142  dir y/virgin/
  143  dir y/virgin/bin/
  144  pwd
  145  find | grep mvsas
  146  find | grep '(mvsas|ocz)'
  147  find | grep -P '(mvsas|ocz)'
  148  dir find | grep -P '(mvsas|ocz)'
  149  dir find | grep -P '(mvsas|ocz)'|more
  150  pwd
  151  cd lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/mvsas/
  152  dir
  153  history | grep ocz
  154  cp -a /modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/extra/ocz10xx.ko .
  155  dir
  156  rm mvsas.ko 
  157  pwd
  158  cd /mnt/sysimage/
  159  depmod -a -b pwd
  160  pwd
  161  fg
  162  bg
  163  jobs
  164  fg 1
  165  ls -lsa
  166  dd if=/dev/zero of=zero6 bs=8225280 &
  167  dir find | grep -P '(mvsas|ocz)'|more
  168  df
  169  ls -lsa
  170  rm zero*
  171  bg
  172  jobs
  173  dir y/virgin/
  174  ls -lsa y/virgin/
  175  dir y/virgin/proc/
  178  dir y/virgin/proc/
  179  dir y/virgin
  180  dir y/virgin/proc/
  181  dir y/virgin/proc/mpt/
  182  dir y/virgin/proc/mpt/ioc0/
  183  jobs
  184  iotop
  185  ls -lsa y/virgin/
  186  dir y/virgin/
  196  dir y/virgin/
  197  fg
  198  ls -lsa
  199  pwd
  200  history >y/c66.bash_history
  201  cp -a r* s* t* u* v* y/virgin &
  202  jobs
  203  dir y//virgin/
  204  ls -lsa y/virgin/
  205  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr/
  206  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr/share/
  210  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr/share/
  211  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr
  212  ls -lsa y/virgin
  213  ls -lsa y/virgin/
  214  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr/
  219  ls -lsa y/virgin/usr/
  220  find usr/|cw
  221  find usr/wc
  222  find usr|wc
  223  find y/virgin/usr|wc
  226  find y/virgin/usr|wc
  227  find usr/wc
  228  cd /y
  229  dir
  230  pwd
  231  cd y
  232  dir
  234  history > save.bash_history
  235  reboot`

If you don't already know - CentOS works like this:

- It loads the bootloader (grub or whatever)
- it mounts the initrd*.img file, which is a hard disk image with dirver modules in it
- that mounted stuff loads your drivers for your disks etc, and continues the boot

So to use drivers that are needed during boot, you've got to chuck them into the initrd*.img filesystem (via cpio) as well as your disk.

Comment: Warning - backticks have been eaten by this web form:  `pwd` should be \`pwd\`